# undefined request on ajax call for json from rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest, request

I wrote the following code expecting to get an array of json elements:

```
var jsonArray = getEmails();

function getEmails(){

    var response = null;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'users/emails.json');
    req.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    req.onload = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.readyState == 201) {
            response = JSON.parse( req.responseText );
        }
    };
    return response;
}
```

But i keep getting "undefined" on req.open request.

Any idea of what might be the problem?

Comment: Try doing `req.onreadystatechange = function() {` instead of `req.onload = function() {` and `if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {` instead of `if (req.readyState == 4 && req.readyState == 201) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I think it should be

```
var jsonArray = getEmails();

function getEmails(){

var response = null;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
req.open('GET', 'users/emails.json');
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        response = JSON.parse( req.responseText );
    }
};
return response;
}
```

You were using `req.onload` to check for the response, well as of my knowing you should use `req.onreadystatechange` and you misused `re.readyState` for `req.status` so this:

```
(req.readyState == 4 && req.readyState == 201) {
```

becomes this:

```
if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
```

Which checks for the last trigger on onreadystatechange (4) and the status code of 200, which is OK.
And as mentioned by Turbod, you didn't use `req.send()`

Answer (score 0):

You skipped the:

```
req.send();
```

method.

Here is an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest